# Keep showing a dialog when validation of input fails

Tags: dialog, javafx, javafx-8

I currently have a dialog with four TextFields from which the input is collected. When the input can not meet my requirements, the dialog should stay open and show an error message. I currently have the following code:

```
dlg.setResultConverter(dialogButton -> {

    if (dialogButton == createButtonType) {

        ArrayList<String> returnList = getInput();

        if (returnList != null) {
            return returnList;
        }
        else {
            dlg.showAndWait();
        }

    }
    return null;
});

Optional<ArrayList<String>> result = dlg.showAndWait();
result.ifPresent(customerDetails -> {

    //Use the input for something

});
```

The `getInput()` method gets the text from the TextFields and tests it against some requirements. When the input passes, the four Strings are put in an `ArrayList<String>`. Else, the method returns `null`. As you can see, the result converter checks if the method returned `null`. If it didn't, it just returns the `ArrayList<String>`.

But, when the validation fails, the dialog should be kept open. It works with `dlg.showAndWait()`, but the downside is that it triggers an error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Stage already visible`. (it keeps working, but getting an error is not the way it should be)

My question is: does anyone know how to do this, without triggering an error?

Note: I am using JavaFX 8 (JDK 1.8.0_40), which has the dialog features built in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add listeners to your `TextField`s, validating the user input.

If the user input is valid, enable the "OK" `Button` (or whatever its name is) if the user input is invalid, disable the `Button`.

If the `Button` for closing the `Dialog` is disabled, the only way to close the `Dialog` is to cancel, which results in an empty `Optional` as result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Does this mean that this is not possible with the result converter?

Comment: The result converter is meant to convert the result. So it is quite possible too late to prevent the closing of the dialog ;-)

Comment: You can also attach an ActionListener on the ok-button an consume the event when the Input is invalid

Comment: @tomsontom helas it does not prevent closing the dialog.

Answer (score 24):

```
final Button okButton = (Button) dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.OK);
okButton.addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, ae -> {
    if (!isValid()) {
        ae.consume(); //not valid
    }
});
```

Works fine for me. Just use filter as it fires first.

BTW it is described in [official docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html).

Answer (score 0):

Assume a Dialog with TextField and an Ok Button.

The button is disabled to start with and is enabled on entering valid data in the TextField (text between 5 and 25 characters long). The ChangeListener attached to the TextField's StringProperty controls the button's enabled/disabled state.

```
TextField textFld = new TextField();
...
ButtonType buttonTypeOk = new ButtonType("Okay", ButtonData.OK_DONE);
dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(buttonTypeOk);
final Button okButton = (Button) dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(buttonTypeOk);
okButton.setDisable(true);
textFld.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    okButton.setDisable(newValue.trim().length() < 5 || newValue.trim().length() > 25);
});
```